# Using Jquery hover event to change css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm trying to use bootstraps "active" class, but when I hover over a different navbar link, I want the "active" to take the look of the other navbar link that are not being hovered over.

Here is my relevant HTML:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a id="active" href="#">TOWER DUEL</a></li>
                        <li><a class="otherNavs" href="#thecrew">THE CREW</a></li>
                        <li><a class="otherNavs" href="./presskit/">PRESSKIT</a></li>
                    </ul>
      </div>
```

And here is my Relavent JQuery

```
    $( ".otherNavs" ).hover(function() {
            $("#active" ).css("color", "#68ddff !important");
                $("#active" ).css("color", "#68ddff !important");
                $("#active").css("background", "#0f2436")
                $("#active").css("background", "-webkit-linear-gradient(#0f2436, #14335c)")
                $("#active").css("background", "-o-linear-gradient(#0f2436, #14335c)")
                $("#active").css("background", "-moz-linear-gradient(#0f2436, #14335c)")
                $("#active").css("background", "linear-gradient(#0f2436, #14335c)")
            });
```

As you may have noticed by now... There is a curveball. My background is gradient, so I had to use all that browser support bullshit, lol.

Im to the point where im like positive this code should work, but its not.

Also, I have confirmed my jquery library is functional, I'm using it in another parts of my code.

I do realize I have no support to "Pop it back in place" when I'm done hovering, but that's the easy part once I get the initial code working.

EDIT:

So I was approached with a much easier method, simply removing the class onhover and adding it back after:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li id="activePage" class="active"><a href="#">TOWER DUEL</a></li>
                        <li><a class="otherNavs" href="#thecrew">THE CREW</a></li>
                        <li><a class="otherNavs" href="./presskit/">PRESSKIT</a></li>
                    </ul>
      </div>
```

And my new jquery:

```
        $(".otherNavs").hover( function () {
            $("#activePage").removeclass("active");
        }, function () {
            $("#activePage").addclass("active");
        });
```

However, this code is still unfunctional. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You want to use active as class or active as id? Your code has both.

Comment: Haha, well I initially did "$(.active a)" in the jquery to try to grab it, trying to troubleshoot and maybe that was the problem, so I added a separate ID directly to the "a" tag, in hopes it would work. As far as I know, the same class and Id name do not conflict.

Comment: _"My background is gradient, so I had to use all that browser support bullshit, lol"_ - well that's because you are going about it the wrong, a.k.a. "bullshit", way, by manipulating styles via script, lol. _"but when I hover over a different navbar link, I want the "active" to take the look of the other navbar link that are not being hovered over"_ - so what you actually want, is to _remove_ the active class from the element that has it when another link is hovered, and add it back again after. Store the reference to that element into a variable on initialization, then this is quite easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `addClass()` when the mouse hovers over the element, and use `removeClass()` when the mouse stops hovering, instead of `css()`, like this:

```
$(".otherNavs").hover( function () {
    $(".active").addclass("myclass");
}, function () {
    $(".active").removeclass("myclass");
});
```

And then add this to your `CSS`:

```
.myclass {
    color: #68ddff !important;
    background: #0f2436;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0f2436, #14335c);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(#0f2436, #14335c);
    background:      -o-linear-gradient(#0f2436, #14335c);
    background:         linear-gradient(#0f2436, #14335c);
}
```

UPDATE:

For your new markup use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".otherNavs").hover(function() {
    $("#activePage").removeClass("active");
  }, function() {
    $("#activePage").addClass("active");
  });
});
```

your code should work if you put your `<script>` before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: That's way better than my idea. This is actually what I tried, I tweaked it a little bit: http://pastebin.com/raw/s9TP3Gt4 So that way it removes the active class (and goes to my default navbar styling) and adds it back when im done. But its not working?

Comment: It doesn't work because: 1) you're removing an `active` class from an element that doesn't have one, and 2) once you remove the `active` class from an element you can't adress it using `$(".active")`.
You have to use a new class like `myclass` to apply your styles.

Comment: Did my new edit kind of follow what you were saying? Or did I muck it up more? (I edited my first post)

Comment: Thanks so much! :) This is an optional question, but what's the reasoning behind waiting for the document being ready? How would I know to apply that in the future?

Comment: It depends on where you put the <script> tag on the page: 1) if you put it in the <head> you need to wait until all HTML elements are loaded ( i.e. document is ready) before manipulating them, or 2) if you put <script> just before the closing </body> tag, all elements would've been loaded, so you don't need the document.ready part. The second approach is considered better as it notably decreases page load time.

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS:

```css
#navbar:hover .active:not(:hover) {
  color: #68ddff !important;
  background: "#0f2436";
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0f2436, #14335c);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#0f2436, #14335c);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0f2436, #14335c);
  background: linear-gradient(#0f2436, #14335c);
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a id="active" href="#">TOWER DUEL</a></li>
         <li><a class="otherNavs" href="#thecrew">THE CREW</a></li>
         <li><a class="otherNavs" href="./presskit/">PRESSKIT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```